# How to deal with this date format `Tue May 31 17:46:55 +0800 2011` in Java?

Tags: java

How to deal with this date format `Tue May 31 17:46:55 +0800 2011` in Java? I can't create a date object with this string.

Comment: How about using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)? In your case that will be `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");  

Date formattedDate = null;
try {
   formattedDate = df.parse("Tue May 31 17:46:55 +0800 2011");
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.strptime

```
require 'date'
puts DateTime.strptime('Tue May 31 17:46:55 +0800 2011', "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
```